# Spring boot SSO with Oauth2 and Spring-boot-starter-parent version 2+

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, spring-cloud, spring-boot-starter-parent

I got a good and simple SSO sample project from [here](https://github.com/shekhargulati/spring-boot-sso)

Currently the sample works as below.

- Start app1, app2, sso-server.
- Load http://localhost:8082/app1 It will redirect to login page of
  http://localhost:8080/sso-server

  username: user, password: password
- On successful login, it will redirect back to
  http://localhost:8082/app1 The page will show "Welcome to app1, user"
- Now on loading http://localhost:8083/app2 The page will show "Welcome
  to app2, user" since we have already logged in.

**Now my issue is the sample uses spring-boot-starter-parent version 1.5.9.RELEASE**

The sample uses spring-cloud dependency also. I read like spring-cloud will not support spring-boot-starter-parent version 2 or above.

So I tried to remove spring cloud dependency from app1 and I could start the application after a tough try. My new pom is as below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.shekhargulati</groupId>
<artifactId>app1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>app1</name>
<description>App1</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now on loading app1, it will show sso login window. But after successfull login, it will throw 404 error.

And if I do the same changes in sso-server application, the authorization will not work. Authorization API wil lthrow 404.

Please help me to fix this.
**My need is, make this application work as earlier with spring boot starter parent version 2+.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [link for the code in github](https://github.com/nkhs007/spring-boot-sso) which is forked from the link which is provided in the above question which is providing all the feature you have expected using Spring-Boot 2.X version.

> In the above code I have moved your code from Spring boot version 1.5.9.RELEASE to 2.1.3.RELEASE and Spring Cloud version from Edgware.SR1 to Finchley.SR1